# Display a datetime column in specified format in MS Access

Tags: datetime, ms-access-2016, milliseconds

How to display a datetime SQL Server column, milliseconds included, in MS Access. Now it specifies `mm/dd/yy hh:nn:ss` format. Any way to add milliseconds to this (they are in the SQL Server table)?

I looked up and down the Internet and found no answer.

Comment: A quick search indicates that MS Access cannot store milliseconds, therefore maybe it cannot display them? If that is true (I'm far from sure) you could always format the datetime column into a string in your query. Either way I have removed the SQL Server tag, because its not relevant to the question.